# nodejs How to fix `browser.newPage is not a function` using puppeteer-core?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to use pupetteer-core but when I run my code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
module.exports= run = () => {
    const url = 'https://example.com'
    const browser = puppeteer.launch();
    const page = browser.newPage().then(function(page){
    page.goto(url)
    return browser
};

run().catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

I get this error
`TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that puppeteer works with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), meaning that most functions will return a Promise instead of the value directly. This means that you ether have to use [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) function or `await` statements to get the value.

**Code sample**

```js
module.exports = run = async () => {
    const url = 'https://example.com';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    return browser;
};
```

Note that the function is marked as `async` now, making it implicitly returning a Promise. That means to wait for the `run()` function to finish, you would have to call it from within another `async` function like this:

```js
(async () => {
    const browser = await run();
})();
```

Comment: Does not work for me either, I receive the same error as before (and I assume the last command should be `(async () => { const browser = await run(); })();` as the one you provided throws a syntax error.

Comment: @K.Frank Hard to say what the problem is in your case without seeing your code. Feel free to ask another question. And thanks for the hint regarding the syntax error. That was indeed a mistake.